# upload file into AWS Secrets Manager using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-secrets-manager

> **What specific changes need to be made to the syntax of the example below in order for Terraform to successfully upload the named file into a secret in AWS Secrets Manager?**

Note that an AWS EC2 instance running Amazon Linux 2 is also created by the same Terraform module and needs to retrieve this file from the Secrets manager.  The same Amazon Linux 2 EC2 instance is already able to successfully retrieve a string secret from the same AWS Secrets Manager.  Therefore, this problem is isolated to uploading a file instead of a short string.

If it is not possible to upload the file object, then a second best answer would show how to upload the textual contents of the file.  Note that the file is an x509 certificate that will need to be used by a program running in an EC2 instance.  The textual contents are the typical length of an x509 certificate, which is a relatively small amount of text.

**CURRENT CODE:**

```
variable "certFileAndPath" { default = "C:\\path\\to\\the\\x509\\certificate.crt" } 

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "example-cert" {
  name = "example-cert"
  recovery_window_in_days = 0
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "cert-val" {
  secret_id     = aws_secretsmanager_secret.example-cert.id
  secret_binary = filebase64(var.certFileAndPath)
}
```

**CURRENT RESULTS:**

Currently, the Terraform code above results in `None` being echoed out by the `cloud-init` script that retrieves the secret.  And also, the AWS web UI console for secret manager does not show any content when a human user tries to read the contents of the secret which indeed is created by the below.  And Terraform runs the code above without throwing an error.

The `cloud-init` bash userdata command that echoes out `None` in the resulting EC2 instance's `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` is:

```
echo "example-cert is: \n"
echo $(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id "example-cert" --version-stage AWSCURRENT --region "${var._region}" --output text --query SecretString)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `secret_binary`, in the AWS CLI you should use `SecretBinary`:

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id "example-cert" --version-stage AWSCURRENT --region "${var._region}" --output text --query SecretBinary
```